# Webpack: How to find all files inside certain folder name

Tags: regex, webpack

I have file tree like `app/components/forms/components/formError/components`
I need to write a rule that tests all `.scss` files that are only inside root `components` or inside `scene` folder. How can I do this?
The current rule is next:

```
{
      test: /.*\/(components|scenes)\/.*\.scss$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'style-loader',
      }, {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        },
      }, {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
      }],
    }
```

but it didn't find required files

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987151/webpack-how-to-find-all-files-inside-certain-folder-name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use

```
/(components|scenes).*\.scss$/
```

**Details**

- `(components|scenes)` - matches the first `components` or `scenes` substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible, up to the
- `\.scss$` - `.scss` at the end of the string.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pLQpXl/1).